# Lambda expression returns excluded values in array

Tags: c#, lambda

I have some folders that I am reading through and processing some files

```
    const string claims = @"\\myServerPath\Incident Reports\";
    const string archive = @"\\myServerPath\Incident Reports\Archive\";
    const string errorData = @"\\myServerPath\Incident Reports\DataErrorFiles\";
```

I am able to read through and extract all the data I need within these files.

I then have the two file dirs, archive and errorData in an array like this

```
string[] excludeDirectories = new string[] { archive, errorData };
```

and I then try to loop through and do some cleanup like this

```
List<string> dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(claims, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => excludeDirectories.All(e =>!d.StartsWith(e))).ToList();

foreach(string s in SortByLength(dirs))
{
    if (Directory.GetFiles(s).Count() == 0)
    {
         Directory.Delete(s);
    }
}
```

Every time it deletes both directories.. What do I have wrong in my lambda expression that makes it keep including those two?

Even weirder, is at the top where I am getting the files to process, I pick up the files in a similar fashion, and this works. Files in Archive or DataErrorFiles are ignored.

```
List<string> processFiles = Directory.GetFiles(claims, "*.xlsx",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => excludeDirectories.All(e =>!d.StartsWith(e))).ToList();
```

When I have a file sitting on the 'root' dir of claims, it will pick these files up and process them. It then moves them to either archive or error accordingly. When I run through again (file now resides in archive), I do not read the file again. The exclude is working on getting the excel files, but not on the directory cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
List<string> dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(claims, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(d => !excludeDirectories.Any(e => d.StartsWith(e)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: YES! TYSM! I made an edit to my original post regarding the first part where I get files to processed.. Why does my lambda seem to work ok there, but not here?

Comment: TBH I'm not exactly sure what your` Where` is doing. I assumed you wanted all dirs that didn't start with any excluded dir. `excludeDirectories.Any(e => d.StartsWith(e))` asks "is there anything in `excludeDirectories` that start `d`?". `!` gives it's opposite. So if something starts `d` we get a false and the `Where` excludes that element.

Answer (score 0):

This *could* be a casing issue - try changing `StartsWith()` invocation to do a case-insensitive comparison instead:

```
d => excludeDirectories.All(e =>!d.StartsWith(e, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: same results :(
When I hover in debug, the values in excludeDirectories and the values in dirs looks exactly the same?